# C# Xamarin: ObservableCollections<Item> resets a variable to 0?

Tags: c#, xamarin, observablecollection

I have in C# Xamarin an observablecollections with the class "Item" serving for the instances in the stack. In the class are a couple of variables, the most relevant ones being "Name" (string) and "id". Both of these are "public get private set".

When a user would rearrange the order of the stack (e.g. moving items up or down the stack) the string never changes and stays what it should be, but the ID, which except for in the constructor is never changed, somehow gets reset to 0.

```
foreach(Item it in ItemList.videoList) {
     Post += string.Format("&order[]={0}",(it.id == 0) ? it.Name : vid.id.ToString() );
     await DisplayAlert("Data", string.Format("{0} - {1}", it.Name, it.id), "OK");
}
```

(some items do not have a name - the ID is used instead)

If I add only 1 item and don't rearrange it, I get the following result in the display alert:

```
Tomato - 24
```

If I did add other items or rearrange the stack, this is the result:

```
Tomato - 0
```

Do note; the items themselves NEVER EVER change, so do the ID's! There isn't a hidden "foreach set all id's to 0" anywhere. (also note its a private get-only variable)

For extra reference, here are the rearranging functions. They take place in the Item class, and the list itself is a static instance within the class:

```
public static void BindButton(TapGestureRecognizer up, TapGestureRecognizer down, TapGestureRecognizer remove) {
            Item item = ItemLastAdded;
            up.Tapped += (e, i) => {
                MoveUp(item);
            };

            down.Tapped += (e, i) => {
                MoveDown(item);
            };

            remove.Tapped += (e, i) => {
                ItemList.Remove(item);
            };
        }

        private static void MoveUp(Item item) {
            int indexOf = ItemList.IndexOf(item);
            if (indexOf >= 1)) {
                ItemList.Move(indexOf, indexOf - 1);
            } 
        }

        private static void MoveDown(Item item) {
            int indexOf = videoList.IndexOf(item);
            if (indexOf < videoList.Count - 1)) {
                ItemList.Move(indexOf, indexOf + 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: there must be something in your code causing this.  Without seeing the relevant code it's impossible to say what it might be.

Comment: Do your `Item` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: I've fixed it, but the fix is so bizarre and strange, let me explain:

I've moved the "new observablecollection" to before I handled the first item (in the page constructor) instead of after it and that did the trick.

This makes no sense, since it's just making an instance of the class and inserting it into stack to be made afterwards and what I did was made the stack first, then the item, then insert it.

So stack-item-insert instead of item-stack-insert.